# Copy a file and replace a system file with applescript

Tags: copy, applescript

So right now I'm trying to copy over a custom .globalpreferences.plist to the system file. Its located in /Users//Library/Preferences/. I've got it to show my system files so I can move it over just fine to a file that is isnt there, but I can't seem to replace the actual file. Heres what I have so far

```
tell application "Finder"
     duplicate POSIX file "/.GlobalPreferences.plist" to POSIX file "/Users/<username>/Library/Preferences/" with replacing
end tell
```

I might have to use shell for it but I have no idea how to make sure it replaces the file.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use the unix shell to do this

In applescript that would look like:

do shell script "cp path/to/file/GlobalPreferences.plist /Users//Library/Preferences/GlobalPreferences.plist" with administrator privileges

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The `duplicate` command does not seem to work for replacing a filename that starts with a period. This also results in an error:

```
mkdir /tmp/dir;touch /tmp/.a /tmp/dir/.a
osascript -e 'tell app "Finder"
duplicate POSIX file "/tmp/.a" to POSIX file "/tmp/dir"'
end'
```

As a workaround, just use `do shell script`:

```
do shell script "cp /path/to/.GlobalPreferences.plist ~/Library/Preferences"
```

`using administrator privileges` is not needed.